# Xcode 4.2 crashes in archive when "validate" or "submit" are pressed

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, publishing

i put together a program. It works and was tested.

for the last 24 hours i was googling/trying to get it up to be validated.

Someone please do a walkthrough the settings so i can set the right checkmarks and submit it.

I have xcode 4.2, iOS lion.

#### ERROR MESSAGE

> Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of all unsaved data.

#### ERROR DETAILS

> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[ITunesSoftwareApplicationDescription applicationType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x402818c00
>   UserInfo: (null)
>   Hints: None
>   Backtrace:
>     0  0x00007fff9134426a __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
>     1  0x00007fff89b73d5e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
>     2  0x00007fff913d04ce -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
>     3  0x00007fff91331133 __*forwarding*__ (in CoreFoundation)
>     4  0x00007fff91330f48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
>     5  0x000000011114ec9b __block_global_8 (in IDEArchivedApplicationsViewer)
>     6  0x00007fff9136ded2 __NSArrayChunkIterate (in CoreFoundation)
>     7  0x00007fff913c9491 ____NSArrayGetIndexesPassingTest_block_invoke_1 (in CoreFoundation)
>     8  0x00007fff92054467 _dispatch_apply_serial (in libdispatch.dylib)
>     9  0x00007fff920529d7 _dispatch_sync_f_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
>    10  0x00007fff92054347 dispatch_apply_f (in libdispatch.dylib)
>    11  0x00007fff92054697 _dispatch_apply_slow (in libdispatch.dylib)
>    12  0x00007fff9133f2d2 __NSArrayGetIndexesPassingTest (in CoreFoundation)
>    13  0x000000011114eaee __50-[AAVFetchApplicationListAssistant   viewDidInstall]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEArchivedApplicationsViewer)
>    14  0x00007fff920508ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
>    15  0x00007fff92051799 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
>    16  0x00007fff892183da _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)
>    17  0x00007fff89219b85 start_wqthread (in libsystem_c.dylib)

Comment: If the app is "caching" you might need to use the Project > Clean process. But if you are talking about a crash, we will need a lot more information about the app / project.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2212766/Screen%20Shot%20uploading1.png

Comment: anything u want Nils. i took a screenshots of some settings. The app is a tabbed view app, uses movie player.framework. The crash happens when i create archive, click validate, type username.password, boom, get a crash saying i can continue in unstable mode OR crash.

Comment: have you set an release Provisioning Profile in the Code Signing Release Section?

Comment: yes, its in the link i posted in this thread.(screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's your XCode, not your built app that is causing the crash.

My best advise would be checking for XCode upgrades, or maybe do a clean install. It's quickly pulled from the OSX AppStore.

To uninstall Xcode you can run the following command :

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Comment: I have added the method to my answer.

Comment: very good. thank you. i reinstalled and got a newer 4.2.1. The crash i fixed too. It had to do with code signing. when i got distributor signiature to work, it validated and i was able to submit.